# How to change frame style using QSS?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

Good day.
There is an instruction on frame styles, here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#setFrameStyle

Suppose I want my button to have the Box | Sunken.
How can I do this using QSS?
I tried to do it like this:

```
frameStyle: box;
background-color: rgb (230, 230, 230);
border: 1px solid white;
border-right: 2px solid rgb (127, 127, 127);
border-bottom: 2px solid rgb (127, 127, 127);
```

But it didn’t help, apparently I just don’t know any word of the code.

Answer (score 1):

If QSS is what you are looking for then I would recommend looking at the [stylesheet reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) and [stylesheet examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html) in the documentation. It has helped me countless times when trying to figuring out how to style something with QSS.

Your style sheet should be enclosed in curly brackets as follows:

```html
QFrame {
    background-color: rgb (230, 230, 230);
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-right: 2px solid rgb (127, 127, 127);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb (127, 127, 127);
}
```

If you are trying to style a button I would recommend doing something as follows though. There are more examples on the stylesheet reference and examples mentioned earlier.

This is ripped right from the [QSS examples documentation under QPushButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton)

```html
QPushButton {
    border: 2px solid #8f8f91;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                      stop: 0 #f6f7fa, stop: 1 #dadbde);
    min-width: 80px;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);
}

QPushButton:flat {
    border: none; /* no border for a flat push button */
}

QPushButton:default {
    border-color: navy; /* make the default button prominent */
}
```

Using QSS in this way will allow you to make changes to how the button looks in its different states, etc.

Comment: So the conclusion is : there is no way to set the frame style from QSS. You need to re-create the style yourself, or forget about using QSS.